# Suggestion for a cheap device that can be plugged into the LAN end of a pfSense Router and allow wireless devices to connect?

Tags: networking, wireless

Do you have any suggestions for a cheap device that can be plugged into the LAN NIC of a pfSense Box, and allow for ip addresses to be dolled out via it's DHCP Server?

I'm trying to filter internet access using the pfSense proxy server, I'm currently using a pretty good router to do this same thing, and I was looking for a cheaper alternative.

pfSense / FreeBSD doesn't play well with wireless NICs, which is the reasoning behind the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally recommend Ubiquiti's UniFi line of infrastructure, which is rather inexpensive and is actually pretty good from what I've seen of it. The [UniFi AP](https://www.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap/) ([Store page](https://store.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap.html)) should be suited for what you want. They would need to be configured by a device running their controller software though (which could be a raspberry pi or other cheap computer.) A tutorial for setting up the pfSense control webserver on the pi can be found [here](https://erikvanpaassen.tweakblogs.net/blog/12480/turning-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-unifi-controller-appliance-%28unifi-4-raspbian-jessie-oracle-java-8%29) if you wish to use a pi for that task.

Comment: Does it filter SSL too?

Comment: Don't think so, the AP is not really designed for that. you should probably use pfSense for that anyways if it can do that, much smarter system. The AP is pretty much just "wirelessly serve the connection I'm plugged into" with a little bit more for different SSIDs on the same AP.